# Cakephp removing cake from url

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting

I have the following site [My domain](http://www.udlejnings-priser.dk)

As you can see if you click the link you will get an error!.

Now if you instead add cake/users/login to the end of the url you will go to the correct site.

Now my question is how do i remove cake from the url and how do set a default controller ? (so that if a path is not found it will go to that controllers index action instead?)

Comment: Why dont you move all the files under root folder instead of cake folder.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari are you positive this will work?

Comment: it should work, try now

Comment: also add the below line in routes.php to display login page by default.  Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the CakePHP is based on relative paths, the only thing you can do is to move the contents of cake folder with one level up.

As example if you have server path like:
/var/www
and in it you have 
/var/www/cake
all you need to do is to move contents of cake folder to /var/www
the path could depend from the server configuration but the principle is the same. I don't think you should make some changes in the configs.

On the second question how to set default controller for home page - it would be there by default, but I guess you have removed it:
go to app/Config/routes.php of your project and see is there a row starting with

```
Router::connect( '/', ...);
```

if you dont have it, add it like:

```
Router::connect( '/', array('controller' => 'your_controller', 'action' => 'index') );
```

Answer (score 1):

The file /app/config/routes.php contains the routing configuration, and default action can be changed there. E.g.,

Router::connect(
   '/pages',
   array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display')
);

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem of .htaccess, cakephp have th .htaccess

/.htaccess
/app/.htaccess
/app/webroot/.htaccess

you have to add below code after **RewriteEngine on**

```
RewriteBase /cake/                 in /.htaccess
RewriteBase /cake/app/             in /app/.htaccess
RewriteBase /cake/app/webroot/     in /app/webroot/.htaccess
```